# Automated injection of props/targets files not working for native C++ project

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am using automatic package restore in NuGet v2.8.50506.491 with Visual Studio 2013.

I have added a build folder to my package with a {package ID}.props file. However, the file is apparently not being injected into the vcxproj at restore time. The package and all its content are being restored correctly but none of the definitions are visible in vcxproj properties.  This may be expected if property injection occurs in memory, but the build fails due to paths that are clearly defined in the props not having been inherited.

If I add an explicit reference to the props file in my local packages repository, the project builds successfully, therefore there is no issue with the paths in props file.

I have also tried adding the props within a "native" subfolder under build, also to no avail.

An extract from the nuspec:

```
<file src="build\MyPackage.targets" target="build\MyPackage.targets" />
```

I have also tried a targets file instead of/as well as a props file, but this does not work either.

I should add that I have defined Nuget.config in the sln folder, with an absolute path to my packages repository:

```
<config>
  <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\Packages" />
</config>
```

Comment: I was struggling with this myself also. Declaring .targets file in nuspec file directly (not by NugetConvention in build directory which seems like it do not work) was enough.
<file src="build\$id$.targets" target="build\$id$.targets" />

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem today, and eventually I realized that the names of my .nuspec and .targets files were different than the id of my package, which is apparently a problem.  Renaming the .nuspec and .targets files to match the package id made NuGet start injecting into the vcxproj correctly.  I'm not sure which of the two files was the problem, or if it was both, but it's working correctly now that all three names match.

Comment: Thanks to @n.podbielski's comment above for giving me the idea that maybe the files names needed to match the $id$.

Answer (score 0):

Injection of `.targets` and `.props` file references happens only at the time when you **install** the NuGet package. This is the same as with .NET projects where assembly references are created only at package install time.

Later when you build the project the package restore mechanism merely downloads and extracts the NuGet package so that the previously "dangling" .target / .props / assembly references become valid references.